# Groupy by: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to do a groupby in the following dataframe.

[image]

I am looking for a unique combination of `ville`, `arrondissement`, `quartier` and `quartier_av` where column `quartier_av` would be a list. The output I am looking for is as:

[image]

Here is the code i tried :

```
df.groupby(['ville','arrondissement','quartier'])['quartier_av'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

I am getting this error:

```
 TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

When reading the forum, i realise that the error might come from NaN. `NaN is a float, so trying to do string operations on it doesn't work`.

I converted the column to string as follows:

```
df['quartier_av']=df['quartier_av'].astype(str)
```

But i am still getting the same error.

Can someone comment please. Thanks

Comment: As there are multiple commands chained it would help to clarify at which location it does happen. The [indexing], agg, join, ...
Its not 100% clear for the reader at first glance, i.e., it would help if you assign each function call to a new variable and specify exactly which function call or indexing step does wrong - explicitly state which function call is problematic.
Secondly instead of providing images a minimal copy & pasteable example would be also helpful to easily verify and test your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try filling na's  using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['quartier_av']=df['quartier_av'].fillna("")
```

Comment: Alternatively if the OP wants to see the NaN values then could use: `df.groupby(['ville','arrondissement','quartier'])['quartier_av'].agg(list)`

Comment: Yes! of course, But it does not match the desired output .. he can replace the missing value with any string that indicate it missing

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to force conversion to string in your aggregate function, by replacing

`lambda x: ','.join(x)`

with

`lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))`

Note that this method will turn `nan` into `'nan'`, which might not be what you want. To prevent this, you could replace `str` with a user-written conversion-to-string function (which might allow you to deal with other edge cases).